# splash screen not displayig in android

Tags: android

I have two classes as Splash.java and Activity2.java!! I have tried simple code for splash as:

```
public class Splash extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread thread= new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {

                    super.run();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this,Trial.class));
                    finish();

            }
        };
        thread.start();

    }
}
```

In my manifest I have given entry also. My code is running without error. Code of `R.layout.splash` is as:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
<ImageView  
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/d"
android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you starting an activity in a thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really waiting for the splash screen to show. It starts and then you call finish() on it immediately, hence disposing of it.

try something more like:

```
int showSplashFor = 1500;//ms to show splash screen
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.splash);

  Thread splashScreenTread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        int elapsed = 0;
        while(elapsed < showSplashFor)) {
           sleep(100);
           elapsed += 100;
        }
      } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      } finally {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, Trial.class));
        stop();
      }
    }
  };
  splashScreenTread.start();
}
```

**Edit**

`AndroidManifest.xml`
Set the package to `com.example` and make sure both `Splash.java` and `Trial.java` are in that package.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
package="com.example" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
```

Set the `intent-filter` for borh Activities in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".Splash" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Trial">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: i have tried a number of approches and each time i am getting : Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front and after this my trial.class looks on the screen

Comment: Check if you have both activiries defined in the AndroidManifest.xml (and make sure it has the right intent-filter), check for duplicate package names, make sure you are recompiling and re-installing the app on the emulator, kill the process from DDMS or in any other way make sure it is not already running when you try to run it because what this error means is that Trial.class is already running on the system. So maybe you double-start it (once with the intent-filter once from this code)

Comment: And one more thing. Try using Timers and Handlers for this, because a new thread for a splash screen is an overkill in my opinion.

Comment: thank you all for reply!!i am just stuffing with handlers tutorial as well "how to debug log/logcat/ddms".so that i can trace what wrong going here.

Comment: Hii Vuk thanks for reply!! i am not getting you have said :(and make sure it has the right intent-filter), i have not done any change in intent filter except activity name including name in androidmanifest.Is there need some change also in intent filter?Also how to kill process from DDMS.i have one doubt:i have package as :package com.example.Trial; and also a class with name Trial.java, is it ok?

Comment: I'll edit my post and answer the manifest.xml, intent-filter and package questions. As far as process killing is conserned - Select the process name under Devices in DDMS and hit the "Stop Process" icon.

Comment: @Vuk I think there is something wrong with your **finally {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, Trial.class));
        stop();** coz you can't just stop a thread in android, it will return unsupport exception,hope you reconsider and change your anwser

Answer (score 0):

I feel that your splash screen is shown, but immediately after that you're showing "Trial" class.

What I usually do is to have a timer mechanism. i display the splash screen, and start a timer. as soon as the timer expires, the splash activity is closed and the main class (in your case: 'Trial') is brought up.
This is in the case when I don't have to load anything from the web or database in the starting. if i do have to load, then i load it in the splash screen's activity in a separate thread (via handler), and as soon as it finishes loading, I close the splash screen, and load the main class by passing downloaded data to it.

i hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, wrote a tutorial how to create a SplashScreen with a loading time (10 seconds):

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-splashscreen-with-progress-bar/

Basically instead of your thread it starts an ASyncTask, you pass a reference to your progressSpinner into the ASyncTask and this will update it as the thread is downloading resources (or whatever you want to do i.e. just wait 10 seconds)